# Can I use egress network policy without port

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, policy

Can I use egress network policy without giving any port.

Though in my db connection I have specified a port.

So will it allow me to connect to ip without giving any port in egress.

Comment: According to the docs, the port is optional: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.24/#networkpolicyport-v1-networking-k8s-io

Comment: yes, you can skip the port, this would allows allow egress to all the ports.

Comment: And what happens when I specify in network policy and wants to use a different port. Will this work as well?

Comment: By default, if no egress network policy applies to a pod, it is non-isolated for egress. (isolation is evaluated independently for ingress and egress; it is possible for a pod to be isolated for neither, for exactly one, or for both). When a pod is non-isolated for egress, all network egress is allowed from the pod.

The moment one egress network policy applies to a pod, the pod is isolated for egress. For isolated pods, network egress is allowed only if it is permitted by at least one of the egress network policies that applies to it (that is, network policies are by allow list-only).